# how to use phpfox session in cusom php script to access user information

Tags: session, phpfox

I have a custom php script for this i want to use the user information which is logged in into the phpfox site. 
Just like in the wordpress we can access the information of the logged in user through the wp-header.php

So i was looking for such like thing to access the loggedin user information in phpfox. 
Is there any function or function files through which we can access the loggedin user information and use the same session.

Answer (score 0):

use `Phpfox::getservice('user')->get(Phpfox::getUserId())` to get common fields of user